# Custom Off Topic close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

It would be useful if we could have some custom off topic close reasons.

One of the most useful ones would be:

> [Close as Product Recommendation](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/117/111)

Any others?

Comment: You might want to put your recommendation in an answer,  so that it could be voted on independently.

Comment: @Undo - Edited and answer created.

Answer (score 4):

> This question is off-topic because it is about an area of space exploration not covered in our [scope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might be able to get help on [Space Exploration](http://space.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm always wary about adding links to other sites as it encourages cross posting rather than migration, however linking to the help centre of the other site would be good.

Comment: Isn't it what we do on SO?

Comment: it is, and I'm not happy about it being there either.

Comment: I agree with Chris. First thing I did on Phy was to deactivate our "move to math" option (and later push for a migration path). It encourages cross posting which we may not really want.

Answer (score 4):

> Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because [they tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.